# Google Play Developer Account re-verification denied after change to company address

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

After updating an Australian company address (with ASIC) and doing the same for the DUNS registration, Google Play has now threatened to close my account due to "Your organisation name or address is no longer verified".

I am the sole founder and director for an Australian company (startup), and I have no documents other than what is in ASIC to verify the company address.

Perhaps there's a company document I can request from ASIC that I'm not aware of, which Google are seeking (without themselves providing explicit direction).

Does anyone else have experience in this situation?

I've done just about everything I can think of to update Google Play:

- Checked Google Pay profile address, for which is currently out of date, however Google does not allow me to directly edit this (provides link to contact Google Pay support).
- Responded to the Google Play verification request with an ASIC document attached showing my latest company registration info, and this was rejected due to using "personal" documents to verify my personal address. The ASIC document indicates my name as director, along with the new address details, and I had attached a personal bill for proof of address, however obviously this was not enough and I have no other address verification documents to use [under a company name].
- Opened a Google Play support chat, for which I was referred to submit the Google Play verification form.
- Submitted the Google Play verification form, to be rejected again.
- Opened a Google PAY support chat, for which I was advised they could not update the company Google Pay profile address, and referred me back to Google PLAY support.